# JAXB How to ignore "Fixed" value from attribute while generating classes

Tags: binding, jaxb

I have a XSD that has following:

```
<xs:attribute fixed="Zebra" name="animal" type="xs:string" use="required" />
```

The class generated is like this:

```
public String getAnimal() {
    if (animal == null) {
        return "Zebra";
    } else {
        return animal;
    }
}
```

I can't change the XSD and I am using JAXB for class generation. How can I use the binding file to generate following code:

```
public String getAnimal() {
    return animal;
}
```

In other words, how can I add binding to ignore the fixed value for an attribute?